# Check EditText Value after every Click

Tags: java, android, xml

I want my Activity to check the value of the String (Int) in my TextView / EditText everytime the user performs an action (inrease or decrease the value in my text field)

The Activity gets called from two different Activites, Activity A has a starting value of 20 and Activity B has a starting value of 10.

Now I want the user to correct this value (if he likes) and I need to check, that the value for User(A) won't get under 20 and the Value of User(B) won't get under 10, on the other side I need to print a warning text + information text when the User increases this number like:
W: "There is only space for 20(A) / 10(B)"
I: "Increasing will bring you ..." and here I'm going to put some values for the given number in my field

The XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/big_padding">

    <Button
        android:id="@id/btn_minus"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="-" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_plus"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="+" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/number"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btn_minus"
        android:layout_width="100dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/warning"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content">

</RelativeLayout>
```

and here my JavaCode

```java
    EditText num;
    Button btn_plus, btn_minus;
    (..)
    if(id.equals("A")) {
          // Activity A, limit = 20
          num.setText("20");
          btn_plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                  int t = Integer.parseInt(counterTxt.getText().toString());  
                  num.setText(String.valueOf(t+1)); 

              }
          }
          //same for btn_minus
    } else {
        // Activity B, limit=10
        num.setText("10");
    }
```

What definitely is working: if(t<20) {...} - OK.
But after every "onClick" the value due if/else seems a little bit long here in terms of Code. 
Is there any more elegant way to solve this?

Comment: I think you probably need to include more code from your activity so we can understand more about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for something similar to this... This code will allow you to increment a value and watch the value change with each click.

```
    int number = 15;
    Button plus, minus;
    EditText value;

    plus.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener(){
        number++;

        if(number > max)
            number = max;

        value.setText(number);
    });


    minus.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener(){
        number--;

        if(number < min)
        number = min;

        value.setText(number);
    });
```